# How to load binary data to x509 object?

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I have a object

`cryptography.x509.UnrecognizedExtension(oid="custom_oid", value=b"binary data")`.

This data was loaded from `crl` file.

I know, that `value` - is binary representation  of object `cryptography.x509.CRLDistributionPoints`, for example.

Can I load this data to this object ?